# Using custom REQUEST_HEADER on whitelist action

Tags: owasp, mod-security, mod-security2

I'm trying to use a custom request header on a ModSecurity whitelist rule so I can remove specific rules.

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "^/admin/index\.html$" \
   "id:1004,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveById=%{request_headers.x-rules-excluded}"
```

However, when I try to do it I get the following error on NGINX:

> Mar 20 16:18:42 develop-node ip[16035]: nginx: [emerg] "modsecurity_rules_file" directive Rules error. File: /tmp/test.modsec.conf. Line: 1062. Column: 96. Expecting an action, got:  ctl:ruleRemoveById=%{request_headers.x-rules-excluded}" in /tmp/test.nginx.conf:28

I wonder if this is even possible to do...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You are trying to perform macro expansion, and it is not supported in `ctl` actions. You can only pass an integer or a range in `ctl:ruleRemoveById`.